# Use GraphWidget to plot existing Lambda metrics in aws-cdk python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I want to create a Cloudwatch dashboard using aws-cdk to plot metrics of existing Lambda functions or existing resources(DynamoDB, RDS, etc). I know that I have to use the aws_cdk.aws_cloudwatch.Metric() method in GraphWidget() however I'm not sure how to specifically reference an existing resource(lambda function).  I would think that you would need the specify the ARN of the lambda function however, there is no parameter in the Metric() method.

Comment: So I figured it out. You can pull in an existing resource into the stack in a few ways.  For a lambda this works:

<pre>
lambda_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:000000000081:function:the-cloudwatch-dashboard-DynamoLambdaHandlerFB6EB8-1HL44T41ZDDG8"
mylambda = _lambda.Function.from_function_arn(self, "MyExistingLambda", lambda_arn)

dashboard = cloud_watch.Dashboard(self, id="CloudWatchDashBoard")
dashboard.add_widgets(cloud_watch.GraphWidget(title="Lambda Duration",
 width=8,
 left=[mylambda.metric_duration(
 period=core.Duration.minutes(15),
 )]),
 )
</pre>